# MATLAB symbolic simplify eliminating exp with log

Tags: matlab

I have a problem like this :

```
syms al_1 be_1
simplify(log([ exp((4*pi*(al_1*1i - be_1*2i))/5), exp((4*pi*(al_1*1i - be_1*1i))/5)]))
```

but the matlab output instead of removing log and exp, keeps both
ans =

```
[ log(exp((4*pi*(al_1*1i - be_1*2i))/5)), log(exp((4*pi*(al_1*1i - be_1*1i))/5))]
```

is there a work around for this ?

Comment: In such cases it's a good idea to look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) (actually, it's always good to look at it) – simplifying general `log` expressions [isn't as simple as you might think](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html#btrwama-5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks horchler for your comment.

This is the solution,

```
simplify(log([ exp((4*pi*(al_1*1i - be_1*2i))/5), exp((4*pi*(al_1*1i - be_1*1i))/5)]),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', true )
```

ans =

```
[ (4*pi*(al_1*1i - be_1*2i))/5, (4*pi*(al_1*1i - be_1*1i))/5]
```